# ¿Cómo programar un JOB con Stored Procedure de parámetros dinámicos?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, jobs

En Sql Server tengo el siguiente Stored Prodecure: **SP_CARGA_REPORT @COD_MES**
Modelo de ejecución: **exec SP_CARGA_REPORT 201901**
El parámetro es de tipo entero en formato año/mes. La ejecución realiza una copia desde otra tabla por periodo mensual, este parámetro tiene que ir incrementando hasta llegar al 201912.
Requiero saber como podría manejar el incremento de forma automática y programar un Job para su ejecución.
**Ejemplo: El Job ejecutará el SP cada hora y en cada ejecución hará el incremento de ese parámetro desde 201901 hasta el 201912. Un mes por hora.**
Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Puedes cambiar el SP para que solo reciba el año como parámetro. Dentro del SP crea una tabla para ir guardando el valor actual del mes. Así cada vez que se ejecute el SP se verifica que mes le toca, hace su trabajo y luego incrementa el mes en 1.  Al llegar al mes 12 puede eliminar la tabla.

Comment: puedes implementar una job con dos pasos el primer paso donde calcula el dia y la hora con este parametro lo almacenas en una tabla de parametrizacion. en el segundo paso ejecutar el sp llamando Normal.. este debe leer dicho parametro para ejecutarse.

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CARGA (@PARAM INT)
AS
BEGIN
    -- @param = 2019
    DECLARE @fecha datetime = GETDATE();

    DECLARE @HORA VARCHAR(2);
    -- cargamos en la variable hora, el dato en formato 12 horas
    SELECT @HORA = LEFT(((FORMAT(CAST(getdate() AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt'))),2);

    -- anexamos al parametro recibido la hora.
    DECLARE @CODMES INT = CONCAT((CAST(@PARAM AS varchar(4))),@HORA);

    EXEC SP_CARGA_REPORT @CODMES

END
```